# Economy Bot Daily Streak

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a Discord.py economy bot that includes a daily command

It gives everyone each day **$50**, but there is also a streak system. The first time they claim their daily, the bot gives them **$50**, day 2 is **$55**, day 3 is **$60**. And more. If they didn't claim their daily in 24 hours, their streak will be removed and their daily will be back to **$50**

But I don't really know how to make a daily streak system, can anyone help? (I'm using JSON to store data)

This is my daily command's code:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.check(user)
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
async def daily(ctx):
  with open("json/data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
  streak = data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["streak"]
  streak += 1
  daily = 45 + (streak * 5)
  amount_after = data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["balance"] + daily
  data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["streak"] += 1
  data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["balance"] += daily
  with open("json/data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Daily", colour=random.randint(0, 0xffffff), description=f"You've claimed your daily of **${daily}**, now you have **${amount_after}**")
  embed.set_footer(text=f"Your daily streak: {streak}")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

so you can use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to check when the last claim was

```py
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now() # a datetime.datetime objekt 
last_claim_stamp = str(now.timestamp()) # save this into json
​last_claim = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(last_claim_stamp) # get a datetime.datetime back

delta = now - last_claim # the timedelta between now and the last claim
​if delta > timedelta(hours=48): # if last claim is older than 48h; 24h until he can re use the command + 24h time to claim his daily money again = 48h
   ​streak = 1 # reset the streak
else:
   ​streak += 1
```

update your data to sth like this:

```py
data = {
    "1234567890": {
        "streak": 4,
        "balance": 50,
        "last_claim": "1623593996.659298"
    }
}
```

command:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.check(user)
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
async def daily(ctx):
   ​with open("json/data.json", "r") as f:
       ​data = json.load(f)
   ​streak = data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["streak"]
   ​last_claim_stamp = data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["last_claim"]
   ​last_claim = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(last_claim_stamp)
   ​now = datetime.now()
   ​delta = now - last_claim
   ​if delta > timedelta(hours=48):
       ​print("reset streak")
       ​streak = 1
   ​else:
       ​print("increase streak")
       ​streak += 1
   ​daily = 45 + (streak * 5)
   ​amount_after = data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["balance"] + daily
   ​data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["streak"] = streak
   ​data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["balance"] += daily
   ​data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["last_claim"] = str(now.timestamp())
   ​with open("json/data.json", "w") as f:
       ​json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
   ​embed = discord.Embed(title="Daily", colour=random.randint(0, 0xffffff), description=f"You've claimed your daily of **${daily}**, now you have **${amount_after}**")
   ​embed.set_footer(text=f"Your daily streak: {streak}")
   ​await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using json as a database is not preferred but since you want to go ahead, you can save the time someone executes the `daily` command and then you can compare the time when the person used the command after the cooldown.

If the difference is less than 24 hours or whatever you would like then you can award them greater money based on the streak for example `amount + (streak * 10)` and if the difference is more than 24 hours then you can clear the dates saved.

Comment: hello, how would you save the time the person executed the command, like, is there any modules for that?

Comment: You can use ctx.message.created_at or `on_command_completion` event which triggers only when a command has succeeded and all checks have passed. Check out its docs here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_completion