# How to automatically add users to a JSON file for a daily streak command in a Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a daily streak command for my Discord bot using Python and the discord.py library. The code I'm using is based on an example I found online  but I'm facing an issue.

(Code taken from - [Economy Bot Daily Streak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67965218/economy-bot-daily-streak))

```py
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

@client.command()
async def daily(ctx):
  with open ("streak.json","r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
  streak=data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["streak"]
  last_claim_stamp=data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["last_claim"]
  last_claim=datetime.fromtimestamp(float(last_claim_stamp))
  now  =datetime.now() 
  delta = now-last_claim 
  print(f"{streak}\n{last_claim_stamp}\n{last_claim}\n{now}\n{delta}") 
  if delta< timedelta(hours=24):
    await ctx.send('YOU ALREADY CLAIMED YOUR DAILY in 24 hours')
    return
  if delta > timedelta(hours=48):
    print('streak reset')
    streak = 1
  else:
    streak+=1   
  daily = 45+(streak*5) 
  data[f'{ctx.author.id}']["streak"]=streak
  data[f'{ctx.author.id}']["last_claim"]= str(now.timestamp())
  with open("streak.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(data,f,indent=2)
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Daily", colour=random.randint(0, 0xffffff), description=f"You've claimed your daily of **{daily}** \n Not credited")
  embed.set_footer(text=f"Your daily streak : {streak}")

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

My question is: how can I automatically add users to the JSON file when they first use the daily streak command? I tried creating a function to handle this, but I'm encountering an error where it adds timestamps before the command is executed, resulting in the bot saying "you already claimed your daily" even on the first attempt.

- Please explain how to properly add users to the JSON file so the bot can track their individual streaks.
- If possible, could you provide a code example demonstrating how to achieve automatic user addition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import json
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def initialize_json(filename):
    """
    Initializes the JSON file, creating it and adding default values for new users if it doesn't exist.

    Args:
        filename (str): The name of the JSON file.

    Returns:
        dict: The data dictionary loaded from the JSON file, or an empty dictionary if the file is new.
    """

    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:  # File doesn't exist
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            data = {}  # Create an empty dictionary (JSON object)
    return data

def add_user_to_json(filename, user_id, streak=0, last_claim=None):
    """
    Adds a new user to the JSON file if they don't already exist, with the specified default values.

    Args:
        filename (str): The name of the JSON file.
        user_id (int/str): The user's unique identifier.
        streak (int, optional): The user's initial streak (default: 0).
        last_claim (datetime.datetime, optional): The user's last claim timestamp (default: None).
    """

    data = initialize_json(filename)
    if user_id not in data:
        data[user_id] = {'streak': streak, 'last_claim': last_claim}  # Add new user info
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)

@client.command()
async def daily(ctx):
    """
    The daily command for the Discord bot, handling user streaks.

    Args:
        ctx (discord.ext.commands.Context): The context object containing command information.
    """

    user_id = str(ctx.author.id)
    with open("streak.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    # Check if user exists in data, add them if not
    if user_id not in data:
        add_user_to_json("streak.json", user_id)
        data = initialize_json("streak.json")  # Re-read data after adding

    streak = data[user_id]["streak"]
    last_claim_stamp = data[user_id]["last_claim"]

    if last_claim_stamp is not None:
        last_claim = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(last_claim_stamp))
    else:
        # Handle initial claim when there's no last_claim timestamp
        last_claim = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)  # Adjust for daily reset

    now = datetime.now()
    delta = now - last_claim

    # Check if 24 hours have passed since the last claim
    if delta < timedelta(hours=24):
        await ctx.send('YOU ALREADY CLAIMED YOUR DAILY in 24 hours')
        return

    # Reset streak if more than 48 hours have passed since the last claim
    if delta > timedelta(hours=48):
        data[user_id]["streak"] = 1
        streak = 1
    else:
        data[user_id]["streak"] += 1
        streak += 1

    # Calculate daily reward based on streak
    daily = 45 + (streak * 5)

    # Update user data in the JSON file
    data[user_id]["last_claim"] = str(now.timestamp())
    with open("streak.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)

    # Create and send the embed message
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Daily", colour=random.randint(0, 0xffffff),
                          description=f"You've claimed your daily of **{daily}** \n Not credited")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Your daily streak : {streak}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

#### Explanation

**Data Storage:**

- The code utilizes a file named `streak.json` in **JSON format** to store user information.
- This file acts as a database, holding data in a structured and easily accessible way.
- Two functions manage this data:

  - `initialize_json`: Checks if the file exists. If not, it creates a new one.
  - `add_user_to_json`: Adds new users to the file with default values for their streak and last claim timestamp (optional).

**Daily Command (`daily`):**

- This command handles users claiming their daily rewards.
- It retrieves the user's ID and retrieves user data from the `streak.json` file.
- If the user is new (not found in the data), they are added with default values using `add_user_to_json`.
- The code retrieves the user's current streak and last claim timestamp from the data.
- It calculates the time difference between the current time and the last claim.

**Eligibility for Daily Reward:**

- The code checks if 24 hours have passed since the last claim.

  - If less than 24 hours have passed, it informs the user they cannot claim yet.
- It then checks if more than 48 hours have passed since the last claim.

  - If so, it resets the user's streak to 1, signifying a broken streak.

**Reward Calculation and Data Update:**

- If eligible, the daily reward is calculated based on the user's current streak.
- The user's last claim timestamp is updated with the current time in the data.
- The updated data is then saved back to the `streak.json` file.

**Response Message and Embed:**

- An `embed` object is created to display the daily reward information using `discord.Embed`.
- It includes details like the claimed reward and the user's current streak.
- The bot sends the embed message to the user in the Discord channel.